# Unable to access parent class function from derived class object

Tags: c++, subclass

I have a question on why I am unable to use the base class function from my derived class object.
I have looked up and tried numerous things that were stated to work, here are two.
Note each of these is in a separate file:

**Version 1:**

*Parent class*

```
#include "Header.h"

class AbsSequence
{
public:
    virtual int fun(int k) = 0;

    void printSeq(int k, int m)
    {

        cout << "Sequence: ";
        for (int n = k; n < m; ++n)
        {
            cout << AbsSequence::fun(n) << ", ";
        }
        cout << AbsSequence::fun(m);
    }
};
```

*Derived class*

```
#pragma once      

#include "Header.h"
#include "AbsSequence.h" 

class Sequence1 : public AbsSequence
{
public:
    int fun(int k)
    {/*does something*/}
};
```

*main() function*

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "Sequence1.h"
#include "AbsSequence.h" 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int k{ 0 };                                  
    int m{ 0 };                             
    Sequence1 object;                                   
    object.AbsSequence::printSeq(k, m);                      
                 
    return 0;
}
```

Just calling the function, which does not exist, thinking that it should default to the parent function version.

Version 2:
I have also tried the same formation with this difference:

```
object.AbsSequence::printSeq(k, m);
```

Specifying that I want it to use the parent class function.

Either way I get this link error:

> ```
> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall AbsSequence::fun(int)" (?fun@AbsSequence@@UAEHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall AbsSequence::printSeq(int,int)" (?printSeq@AbsSequence@@QAEXHH@Z)
> [path]\Debug\Sequence Summation.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
> ```

When I put of copy of `printSeq()` into my derived class and access it there everything works fine.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how do you compile and link it?

Comment: Reproduce this behaviour I cannot. Caveat: To get the code to compile I had to  do a lot of work and may have fixed the error. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Where do you define your "K" and "M" variables? Looks like some code is missing

Comment: To Tom De Coninck:  Yes I have only included the aspects I felt were important to the issue.

Comment: @dogTired May I recommend you use an online compiler to verify which aspects are important to the issue? There is a list in the [C++ tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) (scroll down a bit; after the midpoint, but not really at the bottom).

Comment: JaMiT:  How will it differ from compiling with VS?

Comment: @dogTired (Use an "at sign" to make sure the person is notified.) VS is another option, and it looks like it worked for you. An online compiler might be more convenient, since you can be sure it's not pulling in some setting or file that you forgot about. In the end, though, it is just personal preference.

Comment: _Formatting note:_ when you use three backticks (```) to start a block of code, you cannot put any code on the same line. (The rest of that line is reserved for specifying the language for the highlighter.) Similarly, the three backticks ending a lock of code need to be on their own line, not on the same line as the last line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you write something like `cout << AbsSequence::fun(m)`, that tries to use `AbsSequence`'s definition of `fun`, not the run-time polymorphism you enabled by declaring `fun` to be a `virtual` function.

Instead, try simply:

```
void printSeq(int k, int m)
{
    std::cout << "Sequence: ";
    for (int n = k; n < m; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << fun(n) << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << fun(m);
}
```

I took the liberty of qualifying `cout` as `std::cout`, since it seems like there's a hidden `using namespace std;` in `Header.h` that is probably inappropriate.